# ActiveRecord return the newest record per user (unique)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a User model and a Card model. User has many Cards, so card has a attribute `user_id`.

I want to fetch the newest single Card for each user. I've been able to do this:

```
Card.all.order(:user_id, :created_at)
# => gives me all the Cards, sorted by user_id then by created_at
```

This gets me half way there, and I could certainly iterate through these rows and grab the first one per user. But this smells really bad to me as I'd be doing a lot of this using Arrays in Ruby.

I can also do this:

```
Card.select('user_id, max(created_at)').group('user_id')
# => gives me user_id and created_at
```

...but I only get back user_ids and created_at timestamps. I can't select any other columns (including id) so what I'm getting back is worthless. I also don't understand why PG won't let me select more columns than above without putting them in the group_by or an aggregate function.

I'd prefer to find a way to get what I want using only ActiveRecord. I'm also willing to write this query in raw SQL but that's if I can't get it done with AR. BTW, I'm using a Postgres DB, which limits some of my options.

Thanks guys.

Comment: How about `Card.all.order(:user_id, :created_at).first` or `Card.all.order(:user_id).order(:created_at).first`

Comment: @Bala I want the newest Card per user for all users who have made a Card. That only gives me the the newest card for the user with the lowest ID who also has at least one card.

Comment: Which one gave you the lowest ID? just add `:desc` to `:created_at`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is one of those cases where the AR ORM doesn't have enough power and you'll need to drop to `find_by_sql`.  For the SQL needed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group and its duplicates.  I ran into a related problem and ended up needing to maintain a table of "last record" ids to make the query fast enough (although I needed last K, not last 1).  You can see in the discussion at the link that for a million records the query is taking ooo a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Bala This will still only return me one record. If I have 10 users, and each of them has made at least 1 card, I want to get the newest card for each user. So the query should return me 10 Cards, not 1.

Comment: @Gene that what I was fearing :/ Looking at your link now.

Comment: @gregb Actually the `HAVING` solution might work since you are only looking for 1 record per group.  Try `having('created_at = MAX(created_at)')`.  Of course this depends on the granularity of time.  If more than one record has exactly the same `created_at` time you'll get all of them.  in PGSQL you're probably safe to say `having('id = MAX(id)')` because `id`s never go backward.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found one solution that is suboptimal performance-wise but will work for very small datasets, when time is short or it's a hobby project:

```
Card.all.order(:user_id, :created_at).to_a.uniq(&:user_id)
```

This takes the AR:Relation results, casts them into a Ruby Array, then performs a Array#uniq on the results with a Proc. After some brief testing it appears #uniq will preserve order, so as long as everything is in order before using uniq you should be good.

The feature is time sensitive so I'm going to use this for now, but I will be looking at something in raw SQL following @Gene's response and link.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted beyond performance. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Probably performance, and to make it float to the bottom in the results? I just tested the answer above yours and it actually works. The error you received might be from an issue with the datatypes you used. I just used the code in the other answer and it works great.

Comment: @gregb it's because the people who came here looking for an answer to get SQL to do the heavy lifting via AR were disappointed that the question title misled the "chosen answer"

Answer (score 3):

We join the cards table on itself, ON

a) `first.id != second.id`
b) `first.user_id = second.user_id`
c) `first.created_at < second.created_at`

```
Card.joins("LEFT JOIN cards AS c ON cards.id != c.id AND c.user_id = cards.user_id AND cards.created_at < c.created_at").where('c.id IS NULL')
```

Comment: got this error: `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: ...T "cards".* FROM "cards"  GROUP BY user_id HAVING MAX(create...`

Comment: actually I've tested it myself, and it runs without errors, I've updated the solutions with an alternative way

Comment: Doesn't work with Postgres. The first command gives me a `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:` and the second gives me `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:`.

Comment: didn't give me one card per user

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I am working on the same matter, and i found this one works for me :

```
Card.all.group_by(&:user_id).map{|s| s.last.last}
```

What do you think ?